# Import oracle *.dmp files and Oracle sequences during import

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g

I exported a user's (USERA) schema to a dmp file. I then tried to import this schema into another user (USERB) as shown below

```
imp fromuser=USERA touser=USERB file=export.dmp log=export.log
```

It is currently importing but it initially produced "IMP-0015 - Statement failed because object exists" for all "Create Sequence" statements.

The userB user is a new user i just created so how can the sequence already exist? Is there something special with sequences? I run the import logged on as USERB.

Any ideas

ps DB is Oracle10G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check to see if they do exist in USERB schema and their date created compaired to the date created of other objects (tables)

```
SQL>select * from user_objects where object_type = 'SEQUENCE';
```

I suspect you ran imp before and it failed because off missing tablespaces. You created the tablepsaces and started imp again. But the sequences are created because they are not created in a tablespace.

P.S. Why don't you use impdp (datapump)?

Comment: No that was the first time i run imp on this database. UserB was a new user so there was no objects on the user. There are now two sequences with the same name. One for UserA and the other for UserB. Im still not sure why it showed that error though.

Comment: Does the `CREATED` value on `USER_OBJECTS` for the UserB sequence correspond with the time you ran the import, and all the other objects that created; or does it pre-date it?

Answer (score 0):

Did it try to create any public synonyms ?
The only other thing I can think of was that it was specifically trying to create a "USERA.sequence_name", which smells like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sequences must be unique, database-wide.
Think about it.

Comment: Are you sure sequences are not per schema? Not database-wide